# Обработка исключений в Python: зачем нужен finally

Tags: python, исключения

Зачем нужна конструкция finally, если код, идущий после try/except даже не в finally, все равно будет выполняться? То есть "Hi" выведется на экран:

```
try:
    print(25)
except ZeroDivisionError:
    print("Error")
finally:
    print("Goodbye")
print("Hi")
```

Comment: Как минимум затем, что в особо запущенных случаях даже принт может выкинуть ошибку, и тогда код после уже не исполнится :)

Comment: @andreymal, или какая-нибудь добрая душа выше напишет: `print = lambda *args: 1 / 0` :D

Answer (score 9):

Например:

```
def get_value():
    f = open('file')
    try:
       return int(f.readline())
    except ValueError:
       return 0
    finally:
       f.close()
```

Comment: Но ведь и имеет смысл:
`def get_value():

    f = open('file')
    try:
       return int(f.readline())
    except ValueError:
       return 0
    f.close()`

Comment: @user216037 в комменте неясна табуляция перед `f.close()`. Но он выполнится только в одном из двух случаев (есть исключение или нет). В ответе - в обоих. (Это просто аналог `with open('file') as f:`)

Comment: Табуляция такая же, как и в примере с print("Hi") вверху. Ведь эта команда выполнится в любом случае.

Comment: @user216037. Она вообще не выполнится. Раньше сработает `return`

Comment: Спасибо, вопрос решен :)

Answer (score 3):

Вот вариант, в котором код после try/except выполняться не будет.

```
import sys

try:
    while True:
        pass
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    print('Interrupted')
    sys.exit()
finally:
    print("Goodbye")

print("Still working")
```

`finally` выполняет блок инструкций в любом случае, было ли исключение, или нет (применима, когда нужно непременно что-то сделать, к примеру, закрыть файл).

Answer (score 3):

```
def func(arg):
    try:
        print('[1] try:', arg)
        assert arg
    except AssertionError:
        print('[2] except AssertionError')
    else:
        print('[3] else: return arg')
        return arg
    finally:
        print('[4] finally:')
    print('[5] func')

func(True)
print()
func(False)
```

out:

```
[1] try: True
[3] else: return arg
[4] finally:

[1] try: False
[2] except AssertionError
[4] finally:
[5] func
```